# twitter bootstrap span not aligning properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, when I apply spans the spans do not align themselves into a proper grid.  It doesn't seem to matter what type of element I apply the span to, in this case it is inputs. I obviously want them to align themselves, what am I doing wrong?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fKQsj/

```
   <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="First" />
                    <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Middle" />
                    <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Last" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="City" />
                    <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="State" />
                    <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Zip5" />
                    <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Store" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="span4 offset8">
                        <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the manual

> ```
> For multiple grid inputs per line, use the .controls-row modifier class for proper spacing. 
> It floats the inputs to collapse white-space, sets the proper margins, and clears the float.
> ```